# Can I use C++/CLI (.NET Winforms/WPF ) to provide GUI for app written in native C & C++

Tags: .net, c++, wpf, winforms, c++-cli

I've an app written C & C++. Now, I need to provide a GUI for this app. MFC is the best option for me. But I'm not familiar with MFC.

So can I use .NET to build GUI for this? If so, How? Please be clear.

If I can use .NET I guess I can use WPF too right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can *technically* write a GUI in C++/CLI, but I would **highly discourage** it. C++/CLI is good for writing .NET wrappers around native C++ and exposing it to other .NET languages, but not much else.

In your case, if you're really set on using WinForms/WPF, then I would suggest using C++/CLI to create a wrapper around your C++ code and then building the actual GUI in C#.

Otherwise, a C++ library like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) would also suffice for doing a "native" C++ GUI.

[Here's a quick introduction to C++/CLI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx). This is a quick-start guide for getting started with C++/CLI. Once you build a C++/CLI DLL, you can just add it as a reference to your C# project and It Just Works(tm).

Comment: 1. How to do the MFC & C# thing?
2. Qt & MFC. I'm not familiar with either of these. Which one is easy to pick up & keep going.

Comment: MFC has nothing to do with either C# or Qt. Qt is an *alternative* to MFC. You cannot use MFC from C#, but C# has WinForms which is much, much better than MFC from a productivity standpoint.

Comment: @codeka I think you din't get what I'm trying to ask. I was just asking 1. how to create wrappers of C++/CLI on my app & then access it from C# .NET 2. I know Qt & MFC are different. I want to know which one is easier to learn and build GUI because I don't have much time for this.

Comment: Oh right, sorry... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx This is a quick-start guide for getting started with C++/CLI. Once you build a C++/CLI DLL, you can just add it as a reference to your C# project and It Just Works(tm). For the Qt/wxWidgets/MFC thing, my *personal* preference would be wxWidgets over Qt, since Qt is a bit heavy on the pre-processing for my taste. But that's personal opinion. IMO, both are light-years ahead of MFC.

Comment: @claws: I know. The expression "x is light-years ahead of y" assumes you're thinking of it as a "race" between x and y. You could also say "Qt & wxWidgets are miles ahead of MFC".

Comment: It's a unit of time if you can relate the speed at which you work to the speed of light :P

Comment: @codeka : Please include your codeproject comment in the answer so that I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 6):

Organize the C++ app as a "server", exporting functions which can be called by a GUI "client". Build this C++ code as a DLL, exporting said functions. Create your GUI app as a .NET EXE and let it call said functions in your DLL using Platform Invoke (P/Invoke).

Comment: sounds good. Any pointers that gives me detailed information on this? How to export functions & DLL & how to use P/Invoke

Comment: Creating DLLs and exporting functions from them is covered in the Visual C++ docs. There's a whole section on using P/Invoke to call native DLLs from .NET in the .NET SDK.

Answer (score 3):

This book also deserves particular mention since it covers advanced topics and using WPF with C++/CLI:
[C++/CLI in Action (Manning)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394818)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on if you want to learn another language?
If you choose the C++/CLI or C# route you will have to get familiar with those languages before you even start with your GUI.
Yeah MFC isn't the greatest but at least you can still use C++ with it.
And that seems to be what Microsoft wants you to use since most of their video tutorials are MFC based:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/bb693459.aspx

If you choose the WinForms C++/CLI route Visual Studio actually ships with a template for this. Even 2010 doesn't ship with a WPF project template like C# though so you should get the message that Microsoft wants you to use C# for GUI stuff.

Anyways, if it's a trivial app or program you are porting it's not that hard using WinForms. Actually, it's just a bit harder than using C# since you get to use the same GUI editor in Visual Studio but you have to write a lot more of the code by hand than using C#.

And you have to know Microsoft's C++/CLI since the template will autogenerate code in that and you need to understand what it does so you can ignore most of it.

[Ivor Horton's Beginning Visual C++ 2010](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470500883.html) and [Visual C++ 2008 How to Program (2nd Edition)   ~ Paul J. Deitel, Harvey M. Deitel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136151574) are 2 of the only books I've seen that cover WinForm/C++/CLI programming so you might want to look at that or just go with C# as everyone recommends.

Comment: @daveangel well could give links to those two books.

Comment: Actually, if you read that first PDF sample of CH1 of the link I provided Horton does a good job of explaining the differences between C++/MFC/CLI and even has a good pic to go along with it :)

Comment: excellent!! Why don't you edit your post to include the detailed link. Also please link the 2nd book you were talking about