# Can't find Windows Forms Application for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm really new to visual studio and programming in general. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 Desktop Version (from what I know).
I can't find a Windows Forms Application from the C++ category, while there is one for C#.

Can anyone help, do I need to download another version, a plugin, or anything?
Sorry if a stupid question, I just really can't figure it out!

Comment: There probably isn't a project template for C++ since it's not usually used for WinForma development.

Comment: Programming Windows Forms with C++ is actually C++/CLI, a dot.netified syntax for interoperability. C++/CLI is *best* used for dealing with exposing C or C++ code to .Net languages (instead of using p/invoke).

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: there used to be a preinstalled C++ template in all previous versions of VS. Microsoft just omitted it to promote C# development.

Comment: @crashmstr: C++/CLI is quite suitable for development of GUI applications as well.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did not say it was not suitable, just not where it is *best* used. As it does not support WPF and Windows Forms is pretty much "legacy" at this point, I stand by my comment. Also, [I'm not the only one of this opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2778640/1441).

Comment: @crashmstr: the link is giving no arguments at all, and the question isn't about WPF. Can you justify your *best* ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust C++/CLI is not C++ and learning C++/CLI will not help you write idiomatic C++ programs that use standard C++ functionality. It sounds like the user (like many) mistake "C++ Windows Forms" as being plain old C++ when it is most definitely not (part of my comment!). C++/CLI is very useful, and I use it frequently to interface .Net code with C++ code. I would also question the idea of starting with Windows Forms when that is definitely on the back burner for years now. Alternatives are third party with standard C++ or go WPF and C#. Yes, *best* is an opinion, and that is mine.

Comment: @crashmstr: "It sounds like the user (like many) mistake "C++ Windows Forms" as being plain old C++": this must be where my misunderstanding comes from. The fact is that Microsoft removed the C++ template for Forms applications which used to be there along with C# templates. I am sure the OP known very well it is C++/CLI. Besides, C++ defines no GUI services at all.

Comment: @crashmstr C++/CLI == C++. People like you are the ones who make it hard for beginners to experiment with a new language. For anyone with .NET/C# knowledge, C++/CLI is a GREAT way to learn C++ without getting overwhelmed and eventually losing all interest (something that is common among the C family of languages). And regarding WinForms, it's still the best way to develop apps that aren't toys.

Comment: @antikbd but for people with no knowledge at all of .NET/C#, C++ CLI isn't the best way to learn C++.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are no C++ Windows Form templates in Visual Studio 2015. As I see it, you have two choices:

- When creating a new project, You will see an online dropdown, click that and try to search for "C++ Windows Forms".
- Create an empty C++ CLR project and add a Windows Forms to it. This [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/162326/) puts it like this (credit to the onContentStop, the user who posted this):

  1. Make a "CLR Empty Project".
  2. Press Ctrl-Shift-A and create a Windows Form (under UI).
  3. Inside the CPP file that is created, paste this code, replacing anything in square brackets except `[STAThread]` with the appropriate names:

     ```
     #include "[FORM NAME].h"

     using namespace System;
     using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

     [STAThread]//leave this as is
     void main(array<String^>^ args) {
         Application::EnableVisualStyles();
         Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
         Application::Run(gcnew [PROJECT NAME]::[FORM NAME]);
     }
     ```
  4. Right click your project in the Solution Explorer and click Properties.
  5. Under Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced, change Entry Point to "main" (without quotation marks).
  6. Under Configuration Properties > Linker > System, change SubSystem to "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" (without quotation marks).

Comment: If you want to edit the form visually, then go to `Header Files -> [MY FORM].h` in Solution Explorer and edit it via the Microsoft Toolbox.

Comment: And I pressed the `X` button and closed the designer view. Now I want to open the designer view................ How? I don't see how to open designer view. Visual Studio just turned against C++ developers.

Comment: Thank you, but I have one question: Why should I memorize these steps? Why Visual studio does not create this piece of code automatically?

Answer (score 10):

Though this has already been answered, I feel like this might help those who stumble across this in the future. While creating a new project, directly above the text field for naming your project, there is a blue link that reads "Click here to go online and find templates" If you click that link it will direct you to templates that are available for you to download & use. Simply use the hierarchy on the left hand side and navigate to Visual C++ and you should be able to simply click "C++ Windows Forms" and it will create the new project, while also downloading and installing the template for future use. So, next time you go to create a C++ Winform you wont have to search for it again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click File-New-Project
2. Click online
3. Click/ Expand Visual C++
4. Click windows form application
5. Click C++/CLR Windows Forms fur Visual Studio 201..

Write project Name And Click OK.

Download and enjoy!!