# How to add a control to the main form in MS Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have plenty of Borland/Embaracdero Delphi/C++ experience and so have been given an existing project and told to convert it to MS Visual Studio ***2015***.

I want to create a traditional Windows app (for Windows 7+) with a page control, text boxes, combo boxes, text input, radio groups  and buttons.

I found some official MS documents : [Walkthrough: Create a traditional Windows Desktop application (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=vs-2015), but what I am missing is how to add GUI controls  to my form.

In Delphi/C++ Builder, there is a toolbar with components like text box, combo box, list box, buttons, etc and I just drag one from a toolbar onto my form to have it automatically declared; I could then use an “object inspector” to modify its properties, if desired, and, finally, I could double click the component to jump to its default code handler and add some code to handle `OnClick()`, `OnChange()`, etc.

Question: how do I go about this with MS Visual Studio? Any links, tutorials? Google is not my friend today, so sorry to ask something so absolutely basic.

---

[Update] I have found the toolbox, but it contains no components(!) - at least, it says "there are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox".

1. How to I view my form, and
2. How do I drag & drop some GUI controls on to it?

Comment: VS does not provide any kind of native GUI framework by default. You will need to install MFC or QT first.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404247/cant-find-windows-forms-application-for-c). My next plan is to knock up the GUI in VB and call from that into the modular C++ of the rest of the existing project.